# BigQuery Querying Events Table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**Objective** : To take the users count which has event_name= 'Wallet'

**Problem** : I have limited the query's result to 100 to check so the expected result must be 100 but when I use `count(params.value.string_value)` it shows 124 .

**Code** : `SELECT count(params.value.string_value) FROM "myproj.analytics_197163127.events_20190528",UNNEST(event_params) as params where event_name ='Wallet' and params.key = 'UserId' limit 100`

**Expected Result** : if the query is returning 100 records the count should be 100 but how is it showing 124?

Hope the question is clear

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide sample data and expected outcome as formatted text and not images. More info [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Yeah sure when i run the query its shows 100 records but when i see the count its showing 120 the query us
`SELECT event_date,event_timestamp,event_name, params.value.string_value FROM 
`myproj.analytics_197163127.events_20190528`, 
UNNEST(event_params) as params 
where 
event_name ='Wallet' and params.key = 'UserId'
limit 100`

Comment: Please, edit your question with the queries made. Will be more useful for the upcoming developers, thanks :)

Comment: @SaiSivaSubramanianL I [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374461/bigquery-querying-events-table) your question. If not accurate use the edit link to update. Regarding your question, I see you have `limit 100` in your SQL. Am I'm missing something?

Comment: @PolOrtiz@TamirKlein I have edited the question please check it again Thanks

Comment: @SaiSivaSubramanianL i need your help regarding firebase how can i reach you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`limit` is applied to the result set produced by the query.

Your query is an aggregation query with no `group by`.  Such an aggregation *always* returns one row.  So, the `limit` does not affect the results.

If you want to see `100` for the result set, use a CTE or subquery:

```
SELECT count(params.value.string_value)
FROM (SELECT params
      FROM "myproj.analytics_197163127.events_20190528" e CROSS JOIN
           UNNEST(e.event_params) params 
      WHERE e.event_name ='Wallet' AND params.key = 'UserId' 
      LIMIT 100
     ) ep
```

Answer (score 1):

The query shows 100 records because of the limit 100 at the end:

```
SELECT event_date,event_timestamp,event_name, params.value.string_value 
FROM myproj.analytics_197163127.events_20190528, UNNEST(event_params) as params 
where event_name ='Wallet' and params.key = 'UserId' 
limit 100
```

Remove that and check again.

The LIMIT 100 specifies the number of rows to be returned from the SQL statement. It does not influence the COUNT() in your query. So there is a difference between :

```
select count(*) from table limit 100
```

this will return a single value with the number of rows in the table. On the other hand :

```
select count(*) from (select * from table limit 100)
```

This will return 100 (if the table has more than 100 rows - otherwise it will return the number of rows in table)

Comment: Hi thanks guess i asked the question in different way i have edited it again please check it now